# Get dates array from current/next/next 2 weeks

Tags: php, date, calendar, php-carbon

Summary: I need to get the year number, the week number and the dates from the given week/year (monday to friday) from the current week, the next week and from the next two weeks.

Problem: I can't get the week number/year correctly in the last weeks in the year

Scenary: I save in the database the year and the week number, following the ISO 8601 rules. This works like an user agenda and the user save its activities of the current week, of the next week and of the next 2 weeks.

**What I tried:**

I'm generating and array of a given year and date, like this:

```
Array
(
    [week_info] => Array
        (
            [type] => current_week
            [week] => 51
            [year] => 2020
            [days] => Array
                (
                    [monday] => 2020-12-14
                    [tuesday] => 2020-12-15
                    [wednesday] => 2020-12-16
                    [thursday] => 2020-12-17
                    [friday] => 2020-12-18
                )

        )

)
```

The problem always is happening in the last week's year, getting info like this:

```
Array
(
    [week_info] => Array
        (
            [type] => next_two_weeks
            [days] => Array
                (
                    [monday] => 2022-01-03
                    [tuesday] => 2022-01-04
                    [wednesday] => 2022-01-05
                    [thursday] => 2022-01-06
                    [friday] => 2022-01-07
                )

            [year] => 2022
            [week] => 01
        )

)
```

**How I tried it:**

*For the current week:*

```
$week = date('W', strtotime('+0 week'));
$year = date('Y', strtotime('+0 week +2 days'));
return array("year" => $year,"week" => $week);
```

*For the next week:*

```
$week = date('W', strtotime('+1 week'));
$year = date('Y', strtotime('+1 week +2 days'));
return array("year" => $year,"week" => $week);
```

*For the next 2 weeks:*

```
$week = date('W', strtotime('+2 weeks'));
$year = date('Y', strtotime('+2 weeks +2 days'));
return array("year" => $year,"week" => $week);
```

*When I get the year and the week number, I get the date set using the following function:*

Function receiving $param_year and $param_week as paramaters.

```
$dates_day = array();
for($day=1; $day<=5; $day++) {
array_push($dates_day, date('Y-m-d', strtotime($param_year."W".$param_week.$day)));
}
$dateset= array(
"week_info" => array(
"type" => $param_week_type,
"days" => array(
"monday" => $dates_day[0],
"tuesday" => $dates_day[1],
"wednesday" => $dates_day[2],
"thursday" => $dates_day[3],
"friday" => $dates_day[4]),
"year" => date("Y", strtotime($dates_day[4])),
"week" => date("W", strtotime($dates_day[0])),
));
return $dateset;
```

What am I doing wrong? How should I do it correctly?

Comment: Check isoWeek() and isoWeekYear() in the Carbon documentation: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-week that might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test($year, $week) {
        $pointInTime = strtotime($year . 'W' . $week);
        for ($n = 0; $n != 5; $n++) {
            echo("\n" . date('Y-m-d l', $pointInTime));
            $pointInTime = strtotime('+1 day', $pointInTime);
        };
    }

 var_dump(test(2020, 53));

// 2020-12-28 Monday
// 2020-12-29 Tuesday
// 2020-12-30 Wednesday
// 2020-12-31 Thursday
// 2021-01-01 Friday
```

If you want to add the next two weeks:

```
 function test($year, $week, $addWeeks = 0) {
        $pointInTime = strtotime($year . 'W' . $week);

        if ($addWeeks)
            $pointInTime = strtotime('+'.$addWeeks.' weeks', $pointInTime);

        for ($n = 0; $n != 5; $n++) {
            echo("\n" . date('Y-m-d l', $pointInTime));
            $pointInTime = strtotime('+1 day', $pointInTime);
        };
    } 

   echo "\n This week: ";
        $this->test(2020, 53);
        echo "\n Next week: ";
        $this->test(2020, 53, 1);
        echo "\n Next another week: ";
        $this->test(2020, 53, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, my main problem is by getting the year and week according to the current day.

Comment: $yearNow = date('Y',time()); $weekNow = date('W',time()); make sure you have set your timezone correct in the code.

Comment: You don't need the second parameter for current time, it's default. `date('Y')` and `date('W')` are sufficient.